# Permutation notation for repetition where n<r

Tags: permutations, combinations

While solving a question I got a doubt that if I have 2 objects which can be repeated any number of times which have to placed in 8 boxes then how will you write it in permutation notation of nPr as here n would be less than r?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply start with a couple of definitions in order to describe the whole environment.

**Definition 1**: We define the $k$ boxes as $B_1, B_2 \ldots B_k$ (e.g., $k=8$ if there are only $8$ boxes).

**Definition 2**: Let us indicate the two objects as $x$ and $y$ so that any sequence describing a given $B_j, j=1,2,\ldots,k$ is well-defined over time.

Assuming that we have a total of $r$ objects of two kinds, we could say something as:

**Definition 3**: For any given $j \in \{1,2,\dots,8\}$, $B_j:=\{x \vee y, x \vee y, x \vee y, \dots\}$ is such that $|B_j|=r_j$, where $r_j$ is the cardinality of the given set and thus $\sum_{j=1}^{k} r_j=r$.